# Filtering queryset defined with @property

Tags: python, django, wagtail

For a headless wagtail app I'm trying to query all of the blog pages, find the latest page that is marked as being a hero, and then exclude that hero page from the list of all pages. Reason being, I want to display the hero page as a hero image on the blog index page, and then render a list of all the other pages under that. (I could also just send all the `live()` pages and have react find the latest hero page on the front end, filtering it there, but trying to figure out a back end solution as well).

I created to class properties and was hoping to use one to filter the other, i.e. `get_child_pages` would be able to `exclude()` the value returned by `get_heroes`.

```
api_fields = [
    APIField('child_pages', serializer=BlogIndexPageSerializer()),
    APIField('hero', serializer=BlogIndexPageSerializer()),
]

@property
def hero(self):
    return BlogPage.objects.filter(hero=True).order_by('-first_published_at')[:1]

@property
def child_pages(self):
    # return "SOMETHING"
    # return self.get_children().specific().public().live()
    return BlogPage.objects.live().exclude(self.hero)
```

`get_child_pages` works without `exclude` but not with it (`get_heroes is not defined`). I'm learning wagtail and django and I'm not understanding how to work with properties like this.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `exclude(self.get_heroes)` instead. And please, don't name properties like this: either use a method or name property without `get_` prefix. When you see "get_something" in code, it's definitely a function/method name. When you see "something" as name --- it's attribute or property.

Comment: @SUTerliakov thanks for the naming advice. When I try `exclude(self.hero)` I get `TypeError at /api/v2/pages/4/ Cannot filter against a non-conditional expression.`. The `hero` property is returning 1 record. Is it that `hero` has nothing at that time because of async?

Comment: Augh, sorry, haven't paid enough attention. `exclude` works like filter, but inverts the condition. You have to check what will work; I can suggest (too much to reproduce, sorry) 1) `.difference(self.hero)` ; 2) `.exclude(id__in=self.hero.values_list('id', flat=True))`; 3) `.exclude(id=self.hero.get().id)` (and variations like `id=getattr(self.hero.first(), 'id')`). Third option utilizes the fact that `hero` is queryset of single object.

Comment: And why does `self.hero` contain queryset of single item, do you really need it so? Cannot it return just instance (or None if there's no hero)?

Comment: I'm trying to post the latest page that is marked as a hero, `hero = true`. I figured multiple pages could be marked as a hero and I just wanted the latest

Comment: `return BlogPage.objects.live().exclude(id=self.hero.get().id)` worked! Now I need to investigate why this works. Thanks!